# galois field galois_mul2 convertion to javascript?

Tags: javascript, c, galois-field

I am very hard time to convert galois_mul2 function into javascript.

I am having following function in c

```
 unsigned char galois_mul2(unsigned char value)
{
    if (value >> 7)
    {
        return ((value << 1) ^ 0x1b);
    }
    else
        return (value << 1);
}
```

**Javascript Code**

```
  galois_mul2( value){


      if (value >> 7)
      {
        return ((value << 1) ^ 0x1b);
      }
      else
          return (value << 1);
    }
```

If i give input 222 its return 167 in c code
whereas in my code its return 423.

What's Problem?

Comment: An `unsigned char` is an 8-bit type.

Comment: in javascript i am using Uint8Array its also an -bit type

Comment: No, he means, when you index into a UInt8Array object, i.e., `arr[0]`, the output of that is a JavaScript number (64-bit float), so `value << 1` overflows to nine bites.

Comment: So in JS, just do `(value << 1) & 0xff` in both places, to ensure you keep the lowest 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks I got your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floats. But even if you have a `UInt8Array` object, and index into it, JavaScript will convert the internal 8-bit number into a double before giving it to you, so `value << 1` can become a 9-bit number: try `var arr = new Uint8Array([222]); (arr[0] << 1).toString(2)` and notice the output is nine long.

To fix this, just mask with `0xFF` to keep the lowest eight bits:

```
function galois_mul2(value) {
  if (value >> 7) {
    return ((0xff & (value << 1)) ^ 0x1b);
  }
  return 0xff & (value << 1);
}
```

Then, `galois_mul2(222)` returns 167.